# Combine CSV files with path and name

Tags: csv

I am currently using a csv file to combine multiple csv files with the following code: 
    copy *.csv importfile.csv 
Is it possible to modifiy this code in order to include on top of each file being included its path and name? 
In order to get the following result:

```
    c:\data\file1.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    c:\data\file2.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
    c:\data\file3.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide an example of what you are looking for please?
Would something like this be what you need?

```
    c:\data\file1.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    c:\data\file2.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
    c:\data\file3.csv
    field1|field2|field3...
    field1|field2|field3...
```

You'll need a batch script to achieve this...

```
    @ECHO OFF
    ECHO Creating %1...
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (`DIR /B`) DO (
      ECHO Adding %%i
      ECHO. >> %1
      ECHO === %%i: >> %1
      TYPE %%i >> %1  
    )
```

[original post here](http://ask.metafilter.com/132691/How-to-merge-multiple-text-files-keeping-original-filename-and-date)